# how to send json data by $http.Post from Angular to webAPI POST method?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to pass data as JSON object by $http.Post to webAPI method. In WebAPI method, the parameter of the method is a class object.

It works fine when I test the webAPI method by Postman.But I am not able to pass the JSON object by angular $http.post method-I get null values in the webAPI parameter(in the class object).

Can someone please advise how to fix the issue.i am new to AngularJS.Kindly help.

**AngularJS Code**

```
angular.module('Test.Employer')
    .controller('EmployerController', ['$scope','headerValue', '$http',
        function ($scope, headerValue, $http) { 
            var ipEmployerDetls = {                   
                EmployerName: "cherokee",
                Company: "ABC"                   
            };

            $http({ 
                url: "http://localhost:212122/api/Values/PostEmployeeData",
                dataType: 'json', 
                method: 'POST', 
                data: JSON.stringify(ipEmployerDetls), 
                headers: { 
                    "Content-Type": "application/json" 
                } 
            }).success(function (response) { 
                $scope.object = response.data;
            }) 
                .error(function (error) { 
                    alert(error.Message); 
                });
})();
```

**WebAPI**

```
using System.Web.Http;
using AttributeRouting.Web.Http;

namespace webAPITestProject.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/Values")] 
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        retrieveEmployeeData empData = new retrieveEmployeeData();
        retrieveProductDetails prodDetls = new retrieveProductDetails();    

        [Route("PostEmployeeData")] 
        [HttpPost]
        public DataTable PostEmployeeData([FromBody] Employer empDetails)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable { TableName = "MyTableName" };
            dataTable = empData.getEmployeeData(empDetails);
            return dataTable;
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** I get NULL value in empDetails in webAPI method,but when I test the method in Postman,it has value.

Answer (score 1):

Your routing attributes don't look right for how you've specified your $http API call.

Looks like you want the class-level attribute to be:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Values")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
```

Which will mean that PostEmployeeData has a route of *api/Values/PostEmployeeData*.

You'll also need to ensure that your properties in *ipEmployerDetls* directly map to your Employer class (which you haven't shown), so that model binding works correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.I updated the routing attributes as mentioned.The Employer class is as below-namespace employeeDetails

{

   

    public class Employer

    {

        public string Company { get; set; }

        public string EmployerName { get; set; }

 

    }

} But still it is not working.Please let me know any advice.

Comment: The only other unusual things I notice are that you specify dataType, which shouldn't be required. You also specify the Content-Type header, but that is the default value. I would remove both of those things. I also tend to use the shortcut methods, e.g. $http.post(...) in preference to the syntax you've used but it shouldn't matter. I also find it's usually not necessary to stringify your objects.

Comment: I have implemented as per your suggestion.But still I am not able to hit the webAPI method.Anyways appreciate your advice.Thank You !!

Comment: I just noticed one thing-it looks $http.Post never works(never hit controller,it hits webAPi if I use attribute 'params' instead of 'data',but I checked we cannot use 'params' in Post) only &http.Get works.Do I need to add anything any in Config file to make &http.post work.Can anyone advise me please.

Comment: Hi The issue is fixed ! I added data:$.param(empDetails) inside post and Content-Type changed to application/x-www-form-urlencoded.It worked !! Thanks.

Comment: That's very odd that you needed to do that - it's not the usual way of making AJAX calls to Web API.  application/json is normally the way to go, and the use of $.param shouldn't be necessary. I hadn't realised you weren't hitting the method; I thought you were just getting a null value. Glad you've moved forwards with it though!

Comment: That is true.Even I am also surprised how come application/json is not working but this guy and param are working.May be all Open source languages are like this only, sometimes behave weired..thats my experience.Thanks for all your help !!